# Firebase Unique Identifier (user id) not being recognized and app crashes when trying to access Database? Swift iOS9

Tags: ios, swift, firebase, firebase-realtime-database, firebase-authentication

In my app I downloaded and installed the pods including Firebase/FirebaseAuth/FirebaseDatabase/FirebaseStorage/etc, used FIRApp.configure() in my AppDelegate, etc. I successfully logged users in and out and was able to upload/download data. All of a sudden Firebase isn't recognizing my user UUID. I'm not sure why but it just stopped.

Once the app loads everything is fine (still no UUID but the app actually loads) but if I try to go to a screen that would have to connect to Firebase to get upload/download data it crashes. It happens on every screen that needs to access Firebase but not the other ones. I added a ColorController view controller below to show the line the crash happens on.

In my AppDelegate 'didFinishLaunchingWithOptions' I added some code to check wether the app is connected to Firebase and it logs as "successfully connected". However I also added some code to check for the UUID in a print statement and it returns nil.

Any ideas?

```
import UIKit
import Firebase
import FirebaseAuth
import FirebaseDatabase
import FirebaseStorage
import GoogleMaps

@UIApplicationMain
class AppDelegate: UIResponder, UIApplicationDelegate {

    var window: UIWindow?

    override init() {
        super.init()

        //Configure App for FireBase
        FIRApp.configure()

        //Firebase app Offline Updates
        FIRDatabase.database().persistenceEnabled = true

        GMSServices.provideAPIKey("myAPIKey")
    }//end override init


func application(application: UIApplication, didFinishLaunchingWithOptions launchOptions: [NSObject: AnyObject]?) -> Bool {

    //Make sure the app is connected to Firebase
    let connectedRef = FIRDatabase.database().referenceWithPath(".info/connected")
    connectedRef.observeEventType(.Value, withBlock: { 

        (connected) in

    let currentUserID = FIRAuth.auth()?.currentUser?.uid

    if let boolean = connected.value as? Bool where boolean == true {
         //This line successfully prints
         print("\nApp Delegate: Firebase is successfully connected\n")
         print("\nApp Delegate: UUID is \(currentUserID)\n")
    } else {
         print("\nApp Delegate: Firebase is NOT connected\n")
         }
   })


    if currentUserID != nil{
         print("\nApp Delegate: UUID is \(currentUserID)\n")
    } else{
         //These 2 lines print and UUID prints as "nil"
         print("\nApp Delegate: No User ID Available\n")
         print("\nApp Delegate: UUID is \(currentUserID)\n")
    }
}
```

Here is one of the view controllers that has access to Firebase but crashes

```
import UIKit
import Firebase
import FirebaseAuth
import FirebaseDatabase

class ColorController: UIViewController {

@IBOutlet weak var colorLabel: UILabel!

var dbRef: FIRDatabaseReference!
let userID = FIRAuth.auth()?.currentUser?.uid

override func viewDidLoad() {
      super.viewDidLoad()

   //I tried both of these Separately. I commented out the one I didn't use
   self.dbRef = FIRDatabase.database().referenceFromURL("https://myApp.firebaseio.com")

   //I also tried switching to
   self.dbRef = FIRDatabase.database().reference()
}

override func viewWillAppear(animated: Bool) {
        super.viewWillAppear(true)

   let usersRef = self.dbRef.child("users")//it crashes on this line
   let userIDRef = usersRef.child(userID!)
   let colorData = userIDRef.child("colorData")

   colorData.observeEventType(.Value, withBlock: {

        (snapshot) in

      if let dict = snapshot.value as? [String:AnyObject]{

         let chosenColor = dict["chosenColor"] as? String

         self.colorLabel = chosenColor!
    }
  })
 }
}
```

Here is the crash from the ColorController

```
//this is from line 'let usersRef = self.dbRef.child("users")'
Thread1: EXC_BAD_INSTRUCTION (code=EXC_1386_INVOP, subcode=0x0)
```

Comment: Where you say "UUID" you seem to be referring to the user's **UID** (a unique identifier for each Firebase Authentication user). It took me a while to figure that out, so you might want to update your question to use the correct term.

Comment: Not sure what would cause that to crash...  If you can get any extra details (like the stack trace for the crash) and add it to the question, it may help.

Comment: @ Frank van Puffelen I'll update that acronym now.  I used uuid in short for unique user identifier.

Comment: @Michael Zehenbauer I'll add that stack trace a little later. Thanks for the advice

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem was the in the SignUp vc in which I didn't include on this page. @Justin Doan figured it out. On the SignUp vc I had set one of the class's properties to

```
//SignUpController Property
let userID = FIRAuth.auth()?.currentUser?.uid
```

On the signUpButton action I had

```
FIRAuth.auth()?.createUserWithEmail(self.emailTextField.text!, password: self.passwordTextField.text!, completion: {

            (user, error) in
```

When you create a new account using this method, user (from user, error) is the newly created user with a uid which you can access via user!uid. The userID property and this uid had 2 different values. To fix it I had to get rid of the property from the top of the class and move it within the FIRAuth.auth()?.createUserWithEmail completion block like so:

```
FIRAuth.auth()?.createUserWithEmail(self.emailTextField.text!, password: self.passwordTextField.text!, completion: {

                (user, error) in

         //The property should be removed from the top of the class to here
         let userID = FIRAuth.auth()?.currentUser?.uid

        //This should always print a successful match
        if user!.uid != currentUserID{
                print("\nYOUR USER ID'S DON'T MATCH")
            }else{
                print("\nTHE USER ID'S SUCCESSFULLY MATCH")
            }
```

The SignUpController code, question, and answer is here: [Firebase issuing out 2 different uid's -Swift iOS](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39553291/firebase-issuing-out-2-different-uids-swift-ios/39553318#39553318)

Hope this helps someone!

Answer (score 1):

Just change

```
let usersRef = self.dbRef.child("users")
```

**To**

```
let usersRef = FIRDatabase.database().reference().child("users")
let userIDRef = usersRef.child(FIRAuth!.auth()!.currentUser!.uid)
let colorData = userIDRef.child("colorData")
```

If you are not **Authenticating** user before accessing a node in your database , you need to change your security rules:- 
From : -

```
  {
    "rules": {
      ".read": "auth != null",
      ".write": "auth != null"

    }
  }
```

**To**

```
  {
   "rules": {
     ".read": true,
     ".write": true
   }
 }
```

Comment: Look at the Warning part of this answer : - http://stackoverflow.com/a/39515281/6297658...This is something that you are trying to do with current userID...

Comment: Ahhhhh I think I finally found the problem. When the app first launched, FireAuth issues you me one uid (#1). When a user makes an account using FirAuth.createAccount... with email, I'm getting issued a different uid(#2). The #1 uid is what's being shown in the database. the #2 uid is what's being in Auth. Essentially I have 2 different uid's. Firebase doesn't know who I'm I am. I'm going to post the code later as a new question. It's an odd problem.

Comment: here I explained the problem http://stackoverflow.com/questions/39553291/firebase-issuing-out-2-uids-swift-ios

Comment: the problem was all stemmed form my createAccount vc.  Justin Doan pointed it out. At the top of the SignUp class I had the property set as let usersRef = FIRDatabase.database().reference().child("users"). I moved it within the completion block of FIRAuth.auth()?.createUserWithEmail and then everything worked from there. I really appreciate your help. Hopefully I can return the favor 1 day :)