# App crashes when trying to append data to a child value

Tags: swift, firebase

I'm following the instructions as shown in firebase but I'm still getting crashes even after making sure that the text entry is type String.

Here's the error:

> Terminating app due to uncaught exception 'InvalidPathValidation', reason: '(child:) Must be a non-empty string and not contain '.' '#' '$' '[' or ']''

and here's the code:

```
import UIKit
import Firebase
import FirebaseDatabase
import FirebaseAuth

class BioEditViewController: UIViewController {

    @IBOutlet weak var bioTextView: UITextView!
    let databaseRef = FIRDatabase.database().reference()


    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()
        // Do any additional setup after loading the view, typically from a nib.
    }

    override func viewWillAppear(animated: Bool) {
        let userID = FIRAuth.auth()?.currentUser?.uid
        databaseRef.child("users").child(userID!).observeSingleEventOfType(.Value, withBlock: { (snapshot) in
            // Get user level
            let userBio = snapshot.value!["userBio"] as! String
            self.bioTextView.text = userBio

        })
    }

    override func didReceiveMemoryWarning() {
        super.didReceiveMemoryWarning()
        // Dispose of any resources that can be recreated.
    }


    @IBAction func doneSave(sender: UIButton) {
        let textView = bioTextView.text
        self.dismissViewControllerAnimated(false, completion: nil)
        databaseRef.child("users/(user.uid)/userBio").setValue(textView)


    }
}
```

I'm just trying to update a specific child: userBio and not affect the entire object.

Comment: Which line do you get this error?

Comment: For databaseRef.child("users/(user.uid)/userBio").setValue(textView)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

**Warning**

Avoid instantiating your database reference to a variable out of scope. Reason why :- Outside your scope, when you instantiate a class to a variable you don't know wether or not your **`FIRApp`** has already been configured or not, or in general if that class has even been initialised as of yet or not. Just provide a reference(!) to the variable and instantiate later in a scope.

Change:-

```
let databaseRef = FIRDatabase.database().reference()
```

to

```
let databaseRef = FIRDatabaseReference!
```

And before using it just initialise it as:-

```
databaseRef = FIRDatabase.database().reference()
```

Try :-

```
 @IBAction func doneSave(sender: UIButton) {
    let textView = bioTextView.text
    self.dismissViewControllerAnimated(false, completion: nil)
    databaseRef = FIRDatabase.database().reference()
     databaseRef.child("users/\(FIRAuth.auth!.currentUser!.uid)/userBio").setValue(textView)
      }
```

Comment: Yup that worked, just changed it to         databaseRef.child("users/\(FIRAuth.auth()!.currentUser!.uid)/userBio").setValue(textView)
and it worked. Thanks for the tip on the database instantiation too.

Comment: Small error: `let databaseRef = FIRDatabaseReference!` should be `let databaseRef : FIRDatabaseReference!`