# firebase / swift 4 - wait until firebase is done configuring

Tags: ios, swift, firebase, firebase-realtime-database, swift4

So I have `FirebaseApp.configure` in my `application didFinishLaunchingWithOptions` function. If I keep running and stopping the simulator over and over, it sometimes crashes, saying:

> Terminating app due to uncaught exception 'InvalidPathValidation', reason: '(child:) Must be a non-empty string and not contain '.' '#' '$' '[' or ']''

I did my research, [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37334323/the-default-app-has-not-been-configured-yet) and [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39514701/app-crashes-when-trying-to-append-data-to-a-child-value). Both say this was because I was trying to access the database before the configuration has finished. The former works generally better than the latter, but still crashes sometimes, but frequently.

What I have my app do is that if the user already logged in before, it automatically goes to the default starting view, and inside that view, it accesses the Firebase Database in `viewDidLoad` by doing:

```
let messageDB = Database.database().reference().child("Messages")
```

Just doing:

```
let rootDB = Database.database().reference()
```

is fine, but the first one crashes it... But I need the first one to access that specific group. Is there any other way to fix this?

**EDIT**

Here is the code for the going to the default view when already logged in:

```
let mainStoryBoard = UIStoryboard(name: "Main", bundle: nil) // Get Main Storyboard
let page = mainStoryBoard.instantiateViewController(withIdentifier: "groups") as! GroupsViewController // Cast main storyboard as GroupsViewController

if let username = UserDefaults.standard.object(forKey: "username") {
    page.username = username as! String // Set saved username
}
window?.rootViewController = page // Set root view controller
window?.makeKeyAndVisible()
```

Comment: I'm not sure how you reach your conclusion. The first question you linked talks about configuration, but doesn't mention the error you get. The second question you linked contains the error, but doesn't mention configuration anywhere. It seems much more likely that you're calling `child()` somewhere with a parameter that is not initialized.

Comment: Your reference may be lacking the proper connection `fromURL: “yourfirebaseprojecturl”)`

Answer (score 0):

I found the problem! It was here:

```
if let username = UserDefaults.standard.object(forKey: "username") {
    page.username = username as! String // Set saved username
}
```

I used the username field in to get the current user's information from the database, and since the username field was set after the instantiation of the view controller, there were some cases when setting the username came after the firebase reference, so it would search ref.child("").value().