# Firebase issuing out 2 different uid's -Swift iOS

Tags: ios, swift, firebase-realtime-database, firebase-authentication, uid

I have all my pods correctly installed. My app launches and then when I get to scenes that have to access Firebase I've noticed there's a crash. The reason seems to be that Firebase is issuing me 2 different uid's and the one in Auth doesn't match the one in the Database.

When my app launches in AppDelegate I have code to get the current uid.

```
//This is in App Delegate
let myUserID = FIRAuth.auth()?.currentUser?.uid

print("App Delegate: UID is \(myUserID!)")
//An example print is 'App Delegate: UID is Abcdefg12345'
```

Next a SignUp scene is presented and in that view controller I have

```
FIRAuth.auth()?.createUserWithEmail(self.emailTextField.text!, password: self.passwordTextField.text!, completion: {

            //You can access the newly issued uid from user via user!uid
            (user, err) in

print("SignUp: UID is \(user!uid)\n")
//An example print is 'SignUp: UID is Vwxyz67890'
```

When I access user!uid (from user) I get a totally different uid from what is originally in the AppDelegate.

However the uid that I get from user in FIRAuth.auth()?.createUserWithEmail is what's current in Auth but is not recognized in FirebaseDatabase.

The odd thing is the uid that is printed in AppDelegate is what's current in the FirebaseDatabase but is not recognized in Auth. If this uid is changed upon signing up then it should not be available in the Database

I also have a logout scene and when I press the logout button I get the logout uid as the same one created in FIRAuth.auth()?.createUserWithEmail

Any ideas why I have 2 different uid's? This seems to be my crash issues.

AppDelegate

```
import UIKit
import Firebase
import FirebaseAuth
import FirebaseDatabase
import FirebaseStorage
import GoogleMaps

@UIApplicationMain
class AppDelegate: UIResponder, UIApplicationDelegate {

    var window: UIWindow?

    override init() {
        super.init()

        //Configure App for FireBase
        FIRApp.configure()

        //Firebase App Offline Updates
        FIRDatabase.database().persistenceEnabled = true

        GMSServices.provideAPIKey("mykey")
    }//end override init


func application(application: UIApplication, didFinishLaunchingWithOptions launchOptions: [NSObject: AnyObject]?) -> Bool {

        let myUserID = FIRAuth.auth()?.currentUser?.uid

        let connectedRef = FIRDatabase.database().referenceWithPath(".info/connected")
        connectedRef.observeEventType(.Value, withBlock: { 
                    (connected) in

        if let boolean = connected.value as? Bool where boolean == true {
                print("\nApp Delegate: Firebase is connected")

                if myUserID != nil{
                //This uid is different from the one created in signUp but yet it is what's shown in the Database but not Auth
                print("App Delegate: UID is \(myUserID!)\n")
                }
            } else {
                print("\nApp Delegate: Firebase is NOT connected\n")
            }
        })

self.window?.makeKeyAndVisible()

        return true
    }
```

SignUpController

```
import UIKit
import Firebase
import FirebaseAuth
import FirebaseDatabase
import FirebaseCrash

class SignUpController: UIViewController {

@IBOutlet weak var emailTextField: UITextField!
@IBOutlet weak var passwordTextField: UITextField!

var dbRef: FIRDatabaseReference!
let myUserID = FIRAuth.auth()?.currentUser?.uid


override func viewDidLoad() {
      super.viewDidLoad()
self.dbRef = FIRDatabase.database().reference()
}

@IBAction func signUpButton(sender: UIButton) {

FIRAuth.auth()?.createUserWithEmail(self.emailTextField.text!, password: self.passwordTextField.text!, completion: {

            (user, err) in

//This uid is different from AppDelegate but is what is shown in Auth but not in Database
print("\nSignUp: UID is \(user!uid)\n")
print("Now Look at the UID printed from the above property myUserID: \(self.myUserID)")

if err != nil{
        print((error?.localizedDescription)\n)
       }

let usersRef = self.dbRef.child("users")
let userIDRef = usersRef.child(self.myUserID!)
let userEmailRef = userIDRef.child("userEmailRef")

let email = self.self.emailTextField.text!
let dict = [String:AnyObject]()
dict.updateValue(email, forKey: "emailKey")
dict.updateValue(self.myUserID!, forKey: "userIDKey")

userEmailRef.updateChildValues(dict, withCompletionBlock: {

                (error, user) in

                if error != nil{
                    print(err?.localizedDescription\n")
                }
     })
   })
 }
}
```

LogoOutController

```
import UIKit
import Firebase
import FirebaseAuth
import FirebaseDatabase
import FirebaseCrash

class LogoutController: UIViewController {

var dbRef: FIRDatabaseReference!
let myUserID = FIRAuth.auth()?.currentUser?.uid


override func viewDidLoad() {
      super.viewDidLoad()
self.dbRef = FIRDatabase.database().reference()
}


@IBAction func signUpButton(sender: UIButton) {

try! FIRAuth.auth()!.signOut()

print("\nLogout: UID is \(self.myUserID!)")

  }
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You're asking firebase for a uid in the app delegate without checking if a user is logged in. It may be assigning a temporary/anonymous account to the user until they create an account. Check the "Auth" settings in the firebase console and see if multiple accounts are being created in the process.

Remove the code from the App Delegate and move "let myUserID = FIRAuth.auth()?.currentUser?.uid" into the 'createUserWithEmail' function in the signup controller

Comment: You are setting myUserID within the app delegate method so it is still using that value when accessing the database. Change the value when the account is created/logged in

Comment: This is what you are doing:

1. As soon as the app opens you ask firebase for a uid
2. Firebase creates and presents you with a new uid. We'll call this UID1
3. You set myUserID equal to UID1
4. You create a new account
5. Firebase assigns a new uid to this account. We'll call this UID2
6. You access the database using UID1 even though UID2 is now logged in, because you already set this value
7. You log out and ask what the current user's uid is, which is UID2

Comment: I understand your logic and it makes total sense except for 1 thing (not your logic but Firebase's). Your saying in AppDelegate I'm setting myUserID to UID1 and I'm assuming that's set by the let constant. However I tried not using that code at all by completely deleting the whole thing which means I never set it. The problem still occurs. Further along in the project myUserId is never the same as the one created in user!uid. I have other vc's that come way down the line after a successful signup and I use FIRAuth.auth()?.currentUser?.uid to get the uid and it's a mismatch.

Comment: In your signup controller, you still have "let myUserID = FIRAuth.auth()?.currentUser?.uid" set up before the account is created, try moving this into the 'createUserWithEmail' function

Comment: You hit it on the head! Moving it worked and it changed it in every other vc. You should change your answer so I can make it the accepted one and +1 you. Thanks!!! :)

Comment: I've been having this problem for 2 weeks now. Thank you! 

Answer (score 0):

Problem solved. Here's the new code via @Justin Doan 's accepted answer

AppDelegate

```
import UIKit
import Firebase
import FirebaseAuth
import FirebaseDatabase
import FirebaseStorage
import GoogleMaps

@UIApplicationMain
class AppDelegate: UIResponder, UIApplicationDelegate {

    var window: UIWindow?

    override init() {
        super.init()

        //Configure App for FireBase
        FIRApp.configure()

        //Firebase App Offline Updates
        FIRDatabase.database().persistenceEnabled = true

        GMSServices.provideAPIKey("mykey")
    }//end override init


func application(application: UIApplication, didFinishLaunchingWithOptions launchOptions: [NSObject: AnyObject]?) -> Bool {

        let connectedRef = FIRDatabase.database().referenceWithPath(".info/connected")
        connectedRef.observeEventType(.Value, withBlock: { 
                    (connected) in

        if let boolean = connected.value as? Bool where boolean == true {
                print("\nApp Delegate: Firebase is connected")
            } else {
                print("\nApp Delegate: Firebase is NOT connected\n")
            }
        })

self.window?.makeKeyAndVisible()

        return true
    }
```

SignUpController

```
import UIKit
import Firebase
import FirebaseAuth
import FirebaseDatabase
import FirebaseCrash

class SignUpController: UIViewController {

@IBOutlet weak var emailTextField: UITextField!
@IBOutlet weak var passwordTextField: UITextField!

var dbRef: FIRDatabaseReference!

override func viewDidLoad() {
      super.viewDidLoad()
self.dbRef = FIRDatabase.database().reference()
}

@IBAction func signUpButton(sender: UIButton) {

FIRAuth.auth()?.createUserWithEmail(self.emailTextField.text!, password: self.passwordTextField.text!, completion: {

            (user, err) in

let myUserID = FIRAuth.auth()?.currentUser?.uid

//This should always print a successful match
if user!.uid != currentUserID{
            print("\nYOUR USER ID'S DON'T MATCH")
        }else{
            print("\nTHE USER ID's SUCCESSFULLY MATCH")
        }

if err != nil{
        print((error?.localizedDescription)\n)
       }

let usersRef = self.dbRef.child("users")
let userIDRef = usersRef.child(self.myUserID!)
let userEmailRef = userIDRef.child("userEmailRef")

let email = self.self.emailTextField.text!
let dict = [String:AnyObject]()
dict.updateValue(email, forKey: "emailKey")
dict.updateValue(self.myUserID!, forKey: "userIDKey")

userEmailRef.updateChildValues(dict, withCompletionBlock: {

                (error, user) in

                if error != nil{
                    print(err?.localizedDescription\n")
                }
     })
   })
 }
}
```

There's no change to LogoutController